# Simple PHP Not Populating Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

I am trying to get my PHP to populate my page elements but the page will not output the results based on anything I trying in the where clause of my SQL (even though it works on my server.  I don't know why nothing happens when this page is run with a where parameter (the posted variable is being captured).  Let me know if you need more information.

```
<?php

//start output buffering 
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

session_name('shipshapeLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require('connect.php');

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Organization Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$businessName = $_POST['companies'];

echo $businessName;

     //check if username or email is already registered
         $query = "SELECT * FROM Businesses_profiles WHERE business_name = :businessName";
      //now lets update what :user should be
          $query_params = array(
        ':businessName' => $businessName,
        );

    try 
    {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
    }

//fetching all the rows from the query
$profileRow = $stmt->fetch();
while ($profileRow = $stmt->fetch()) 
{ 
?>
<h1>Name</h1>
<p><?php echo $profileRow['business_name'];?></p>
<h1>Description</h1>
<p><?php echo $profileRow['description'];?></p>
<h1>Address</h1>
<p><?php echo $profileRow['address'];?></p>
<h1>Phone</h1>
<p><?php echo $profileRow['contact_phone'];?></p>
<h1>Email</h1>
<p><?php echo $profileRow['contact_email'];?></p>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
//end output buffering
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Try removing `$result =` from `$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);` and the `$profileRow = $stmt->fetch();` before `while ($profileRow = $stmt->fetch())`

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the $profileRow above the while loop.

```
/fetching all the rows from the query
$profileRow = $stmt->fetch();**
while ($profileRow = $stmt->fetch()) 
{ 
?>
```